# Graphite/Logstash and Multiple Clients - Best Practices?

Tags: security, ssl, logstash, graphite

In the process of implementing a centralized Graphite Server with multiple nodes.

Right now, nodes route output from logstash with the `graphite` filter directly to the `carbon-cache` on the server. 
Security is ensured via a firewall (`ufw`) whitelist. Is this a reasonable approach?

Or would one rather go the slightly more cumbersome road w/ `logstash-forwarder` and SSL-certs? Thanks.

Comment: Best practice from a security or a scalability point of view?

Comment: I went with logstash-forwarder and certs. Logstash is way too heavy to be deployed to every client. Thanks anyway.